# How to Handle screen touch events with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

When working with UIKit I was handling within UIView or in a UIViewController.

> func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set, 
>                with event: UIEvent?)

How to handle a touch events with SwiftUI?

Comment: Checkout this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures/adding_interactivity_with_gestures

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Easiest thing is to add a DragGesture.  [Check out](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/draggesture/value) `DragGesture.Value` to get a sense of what information you have available.

```
Circle()
    .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 5, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged { value in
              self.dragLocation = value.location
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
              self.dragLocation = .zero
            }
    )
```

You can use `minimumDistance: 0` in order to have a gesture that starts updating immediately, similar to `touchesBegan(...)` in UIKit.

Answer (score 4):

As another way, We have way of creating a custom button.
SwiftUI provides ButtonStyle, PrimitiveButtonStyle and more.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyle

In fact, Button does not create a label by myself, Button has Style and delegates creating the label to Style.

So, Style has `makeBody` method and we can get a configuration object.
That object has label passed from outside and `isPressed` flag.

`isPressed` will be changed touchDown and touchUpInside events.

I've created the custom button style. That adds an overlay when the component is getting a touch.

https://www.notion.so/muukii/Create-custom-highlight-component-Like-subclassing-UIControl-a4e231ffa3624dfda96141a2f60588f1

Sample code

```
struct OverlayButton<Content: View>: View {

  private let content: Content

  init(
    @ViewBuilder _ content: () -> Content
  ) {
    self.content = content()
  }

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {}) { content }
      .buttonStyle(_ButtonStyle())    
  }

  private struct _ButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> AnyView {
      if configuration.isPressed {
        return AnyView(
          configuration.label
            .background(Color(white: 0.96))
        )
      } else {
        return AnyView(
          configuration.label
            .background(Color(white: 1, opacity: 0.0001))
        )
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I hope that will be your idea.